# How to solve jquery sortable each function after vue-js pagination axios callback?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, axios, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to get array of rows Position when I use jquery sortable in my vue-js code.
everything works fine, but when I go to the next or previous page from current page ( with ajax pagination ) on target page array of rows Position conflict with current page array of rows Position !! 
it seems that array of current and new page rows Position will be mixed!
but when i use inspect element every thing is good and there is no problem, while .each function of jquery ui can not get new rows Position correctly.

I am using Laravel 5.6 , PHP 7.2 , Vue-js 2.5 , Jquery 2.0.3, Jquery ui 1.12.1

```
            <tbody class="sortableTbody">
            <tr class="sortableTr" v-for="(item, index) in items" :data-position ="item.position"> <td class="txtc">@{{ item.name }}</td> </tr>
            </tbody>

            $(".sortableTbody").sortable({
              axis:'y',cursor: "move", update : function(event, ui){
                var namearrays = [];
                $('.sortableTbody tr.sortableTr').each(function(index,element) {
                   console.log($(this).data('position'));
                });
              }
            });
```

==============

```
            pagination is Page 1 (Before using sortable):
            <tbody class="sortableTbody">
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="1">Name1</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="2">Name2</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="3">Name3</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="4">Name4</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="5">Name5</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            Array is : [1,2,3,4,5] ✓


            pagination is Page 1 (After using sortable):
            <tbody class="sortableTbody">
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="2">Name2</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="3">Name3</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="1">Name1</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="4">Name4</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="5">Name5</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            Result of Page1  : [2,3,1,4,5] ✓
```

==============

```
            pagination is Page 2 (Before using sortable):
            <tbody class="sortableTbody">
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="6">Name6</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="7">Name7</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="8">Name8</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="9">Name9</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            Array is : [6,7,8,9] ✓

            pagination is Page 2 (After using sortable):
            <tbody class="sortableTbody">
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="7">Name7</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="6">Name6</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="8">Name8</td></tr>
            <tr class="sortableTr"><td data-position="9">Name9</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            Result of Page2 : [3,2,8,9] χ ( confilicts Page1 and Page2 array )
```

==============

```
            while it must be [7,6,8,9] ✓
```

Comment: Please try and post a reproducible sample (into your post, by using the `<>` button). It's probably unrelated with vue.js, so you can use dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

I myself found it

I must use :

```
console.log( $(this).attr('data-position') );
```

instead of :

```
console.log( $(this).data('position') );
```